# Where to use the jQuery.data and can I view the data on the server side?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In different words, can I use the `jQuery.data(this, "isDirty", "very")` on the server side to add some special processing to the textBox controls, when the page has posted back?

Answer (score 2):

`.data` adds something to the logical DOM, not the actual DOM. The only way to get the data back onto the server is to send it to the server. You could always save it into a textfield as a JSON array and parse it on the server.

Comment: well, when the page posts, everything that had been changed with jQuery .val("Control Data") will show up to the server thorugh the post back, so I was wondering if there was something along the lines but with some attributes just so the server knows the control is "dirty"?

Comment: @TheChad No, not really. Something could be hacked up, but it would involve additional fields. In fact, using a hidden field is probably the only way I would tell you to do it if you didn't want to use an array for that information.

Comment: what do you mean an additional field? Just an invisible store control to where I would append Client Control ID when their values change on the client? If thats the case it sounds doable but is very much by a brute force type of deal...

Comment: I actually mean <asp:HiddenField> in your case. I don't advise other kludges that don't revolve around that, to be honest.